# SSRS freeze column and row together

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, freeze

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a SSRS report with huge set of data, so I made freeze with "FixedData" function for 2 rows (column names) and first 2 columns with important data which user should always see while using this report.

And got such result:

1. If the user scrolls to the right - it's ok, first 2 columns follow the screen
2. If the user scrolls down - it's ok, first 2 rows follow the screen

But

3. If the user uses both ways of scroll (scroll right, then down OR scroll down then right), this is not ok, because user doesn't see the headers of the first two columns anymore.

The image with example you can see here:

[3-rd case result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrjyN.jpg)

I hope very much for your help, If there is any way to make this report correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem of VS preview function, and I didn't have this problem after deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the properties under General Tab of the tablix instead of the Fixed Data property. Then under Row Headers and Column Headers. Tick the selection that says "Keep header visible while scrolling"